# Python not letting me import any libraries in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, pandas, import

I am trying to import `pandas`:

```
import pandas
```

but when I do I get the following error:

```
File "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Code/PythonCode/PipesML/src/random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: cannot import name SystemRandom
```

I have tried uninstalling and then reinstalling `pandas` and this still hasn't worked. I have even tried switching from `Visual Studio` to `Atom`.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I think ```random.py```, the name of your file is the cause of the error. This might be shadowing ```numpy```'s ```random``` module

Comment: How would this be the case? @Sujay

Comment: Additional info: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14860

Comment: Try to rename the file to something else

Comment: the name of your file may cause this problem, but you always can use a virtual environment to avoid this problem.